# Using FilePathResult for returning filestream to UI in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Action in controller as

```
public ActionResult Download()    
{ 
    return File(FileStream, "application/octet-stream", fileName); 
}
```

If I want to use **FilePathresult** as:

```
public FilePathResult Download()
{ 
    return File(FileStream, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
}
```

can I call the `Download()` on click of a button like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("FileDownload", "Download", new { file = item.FileName, GuID = item.DocumentGuID }) /text).Width(10);
```

Also is the implementation of `Download()` is correct in the second instance i.e.,in

```
public FilePathResult Download()
```

?

Comment: Why do not you try and see for yourself? If you already didi, what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ActionLink` defines parameters that you want to pass so you will need to add those to your action

```
@Html.ActionLink("FileDownload", "Download", new { file = item.FileName, GuID = item.DocumentGuID }) /text).Width(10);
```

I'm not sure what `/text.Width(10);` is doing there but a properly formed `ActionLink` with parameters also must define the Html Attributes as the last parameter, just pass in `null`.

Here is an example of a properly formed `ActionLink`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = 10}, null)
```

You have a `file` and a `GuID` parameter in your link, so add those to your action as parameters.

```
public FilePathResult Download(string file, Guid GuID)
{ 
    return File(FileStream, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
}
```

Give it a try and let us know what happens :-)

Happy coding!